# Problems creating Flutter APK on Android after Firebase setup

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

I am writing an app for Android in Flutter. Initially, when I built the APK, it worked correctly on a device. However, after configuring the app for using the firebase cloud message (mainly in the pubspec.yaml and various source .dart files), it builds an APK that does not work.

tried to clean/repair the dart cache --> nothing
tried flutter pub get/upgrade/outdated --> nothing

these are the files in my project:

- android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="studioc5"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility?hl=en and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

- this the "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java":

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.Log;

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;

/**
 * Generated file. Do not edit.
 * This file is generated by the Flutter tool based on the
 * plugins that support the Android platform.
 */
@Keep
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  private static final String TAG = "GeneratedPluginRegistrant";
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_core, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin", e);
    }
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_messaging, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin", e);
    }
  }
}
```

- this the "app/build.graddle":

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.studioc5"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.studioc5"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

- this are the dependencies in the pubspec.yaml:

```
  cupertino_icons: 1.0.6
  firebase_messaging: 14.7.4
  firebase_core: 2.27.0
  http: 1.2.0
  rounded_expansion_tile: 0.0.13
```

- this is the main.dart (the *** substitute the real datas):

```
void main() async {
       await Firebase.initializeApp(
       options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(const MyHomePage());
}
```

as i said tried to repair/reset the cache, reinstalled android studio, created a new flutter project, tried to manually change the pubspec.yaml dependencies, reinstall the flutter sdk... nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

solved!
instead of:

```
void main() async {
       await Firebase.initializeApp(
       options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(const MyHomePage());
}
```

forgot to call WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(), and that was causing all the problems:

```
void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(MyHomePage());

}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Try: `flutter clean`
Then: `flutter pub get`.
also Its good to close the app and run it again after adding each package, specially packages seal with native part and device resources.

Comment: tried a lot of times, when i run 'flutter build apk' i get this warning:

'Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\ilmit\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_messaging-14.7.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
'